# Dask Dataframe "ValueError: Data is compressed as snappy but we don't have this installed"

Tags: python, dask, kubernetes-helm, pyarrow

python-snappy appears to be installed - Dask returns a ValueError.

Helm Config for jupyter and workers:

```
env:
  - name: EXTRA_CONDA_PACKAGES
    value: numba xarray s3fs python-snappy pyarrow ruamel.yaml -c conda-forge
  - name: EXTRA_PIP_PACKAGES
    value: dask-ml --upgrade
```

The containers shows python-snappy (via conda list)

The dataframe is loaded from a multi-part parquet file generated by Apache Drill:

```
files = ['s3://{}'.format(f) for f in fs.glob(path='{}/*.parquet'.format(filename))]
df = dd.read_parquet(files)
```

Running `len(df)` on the dataframe returns:

```
distributed.utils - ERROR - Data is compressed as snappy but we don't have this installed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 622, in log_errors
    yield
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 921, in _handle_report
    six.reraise(*clean_exception(**msg))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 692, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 203, in read
    msg = yield from_frames(frames, deserialize=self.deserialize)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1099, in run
    return
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 315, in wrapper
    future.set_result(_value_from_stopiteration(e))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/comm/utils.py", line 75, in from_frames
    res = _from_frames()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/comm/utils.py", line 61, in _from_frames
    return protocol.loads(frames, deserialize=deserialize)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 96, in loads
    msg = loads_msgpack(small_header, small_payload)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 171, in loads_msgpack
    " installed" % str(header['compression']))
ValueError: Data is compressed as snappy but we don't have this installed
```

Can anyone please suggest a correct configuration here or remediation steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error actually isn't coming from reading your parquet files, it's coming from how Dask compresses data between machines.  You can probably resolve this by installing or not installing `python-snappy` consistently on all of your client/scheduler/worker pods.

You should do either of the following:

1. Remove python-snappy from your list of conda packages for your `jupyter` and `worker` pods.  If you're using `pyarrow` then this is unnecessary, I believe that Arrow includes snappy at the C++ level.
2. Add `python-snappy` to your `scheduler` pod

FWIW I personally recommend `lz4` for inter-machine compression over `snappy`.

Comment: A little necromantic but, how does one make dask use pyarrow or lz4 instead of snappy?

Comment: If you install lz4 then Dask will prefer that to snappy.  PyArrow is not a compression format.